# URxvt not working properly with backslash characters \n and \t (given my particular ~/.bashrc configuration)

Tags: bash, escape-characters, rxvt

I have the following at the bottom of my `~/.bashrc` which shows the last command run and the current working directory at the time of the last command in the title of my terminal window.

```
trap 'echo -ne "\033]2;$(history 1 | cut -d" " -f3-) ••• $(pwd)\007"' DEBUG
```

If I remove this, then URxvt functions as expected with \n and \t. Here is the expected behavior (which functions properly with other terminals, for example lxterminal).

```
~$ echo -e "thank\tyou"
thank   you
```

However, URxvt does the following:

```
~$ echo -e "thank\tyou"
you" ••• /home/brockthank   you
```

I have tried omitting different parts of the command in my `~/.bashrc` but have not had any luck. I know that the development of URxvt stopped in 2016, but I really like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trap 'last_cmd=$(history 1 | cut -d" " -f3-); echo $last_cmd ••• $(pwd) | awk '\''!/\007/ {printf "\033]0;%s\007", $0}'\' DEBUG
```